# Python (pygame) Sin, Cos and Tan

Tags: python, pygame, trigonometry

I noticed there was a `sin`, `cos` and `tan` function in Python.

So, I thought I would use these to make a way of aiming in my game, unfortunately, the word description of `sin`,`cos`,`tan`,`asin`,`acos` and `atan` are very confusing.

I know how to do all the `sin`, `cos` and `tan` rules from school, I just need to apply them to the code. So, here's what I need to do, I just need to know which one I must use:

I have

1. The Angle
2. The Hypotenuse
   (I'm just keeping that the value of how far I want the object to travel before I blit it again)

From the angle, I want to work out either/both the opposite and adjacent.
The hypotenuse is going to be `sin/asin` and `cos/acos`. Which one? I don't know.

How to I input my numbers? Do I just do `aim = cos(angle,hyp)` or do I have to apply some other calculations?

Comment: What should be confusing? Usage of the math.* method is carefully and extensivly documented?! Did you do any research at all?

Comment: "unfortunately, the word description of sin,cos,tan,asin,acos and atan are very confusing" did you read my post at all? I wanted more of a description, I just added my example to make sure I was getting the correct result. Now I cannot up these good answers below, because you ruined my reputation.

Comment: What @PrincessOftheUniverse probably means is that these functions are not extensively documented in Python because they are well known mathematical functions and they are thoroughly explained in many places such as in [the Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine). Python documentation has nothing to add to that.

Comment: If you don't know what sin, cos etc is then please repeat your class in school. We are not here for teaching you elementary geometry - especially when you have no motiviation researching yourself.  A downvote from me for being lazy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formulae are:

```
adjacent = hypothenuse * math.cos(angle)
opposite = hypothenuse * math.sin(angle)
```

where `angle` is in radians.

Comment: Yes, this is EXACTLY what I was asking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your wording is a bit confusing... but what I understand is that you have a point in the 2D space and you want to advance it a particular distance (hypotenuse) aiming a specified angle above the horizon. If so:

```
newX = oldX + dist * cos(angle)
newY = oldY + dist * sin(angle)
```

That assumes that `angle` is in radians, that the Y axis is positive upwards and that the angle is 0 aiming to the right and PI/2 to the top. If these are not the case you may need to wiggle the signs a little.

Comment: Yes, thankyou, this helped a lot. I'm sorry, I'm not very good at explaining things through typing. :). I would up you but someone downed my post, so I lost my reputation.